# Rerender component properly when I'm logged in

Tags: reactjs

I'm working with **React** and I've made a **navigation bar** which should change the content when you are logged in.

For example you have `home register login` and once you're logged in you have `home logout`.

The problem is the *first time* the navigation bar doesn't change after the redirection once you logged in successfully and I don't understand why.

**The login page**:

```
export default class Login extends React.Component {
    render() {
        if (localStorage.getItem("jwt-token")) {
            return (
                <Redirect to = "/home" />
            );
        }
        return (
            <div id="main">
                <NavBar />
                <div id="body">
                    Login
                    <LoginForm />
                </div>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**This is the in the LogginForm**

```
   render() {
       if (this.state.isLogged === true) {
           return (
               <Redirect to = {{ pathname: "/home" }} />
           );
       }
       ... //rest of the form when you're not logged in.
   }
```

**and the home page:**

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="main">
                <NavBar />
                <div id="body">
                    Home
                </div>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**and this is my navigation bar component:**

```
export default class NavBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLogged: undefined,
            login: "",
        }
    }

    async componentWillMount() {
        let token = localStorage.getItem("jwt-token");
        console.log(token);
        if (token) {
            let decodedToken = jwt.decode(token, "secretKey");
            this.setState({
                isLogged: true,
                login: decodedToken.userInfo.login,
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.isLogged === true) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><Link to="/home">Home</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/logout">Logout</Link> [{this.state.login}]</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            );
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to="/home">Home</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/register">Register</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/login">Login</Link></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**P/s:** *pretty simple, I just try to understand how it works.*

So as I said the first time when it redirects to the home page, my navbar is like if i wasn't authenticated but I am. When i refresh the page my navbar finally appears like if I was authenticated.

My question is: **why do I need to reload the page?**

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

for those who want to know the solution,
it just in the component LoginForm i set my token after setState then the render was made before the token was registered.

I just inversed the 2 lines and it worked perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

As react docs recommends:

> UNSAFE_componentWillMount() is invoked just before mounting occurs. It is called before render(), therefore calling setState() synchronously in this method will not trigger an extra rendering. Generally, we recommend using the constructor() instead for initializing state.
>
> Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method. For those use cases, use componentDidMount() instead.

Also see [this](https://vasanthk.gitbooks.io/react-bits/anti-patterns/04.setState-in-componentWillMount.html).

I think you should move your logic from `componentWillMount` to `constructor` method. It should solve the issue.

Edit:
Something like this:

```
constructor() {
    super(props);
   let isLogged = false
   let login = undefined
   let token = localStorage.getItem("jwt-token");
   if (token) {
     let decodedToken = jwt.decode(token, "secretKey");
     isLogged= true
     login = decodedToken.userInfo.login
   }
   this.state = {
        isLogged: undefined,
        login: "",
   }
}
```

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by "move your loginc from componentWillMount to constructor" ?

I didn't get it

Comment: By logic, I mean the `componentWillMount` body.

Comment: I tried it doesn't solve the problem, the first time the navbar is not updated

Comment: Could you please create a runnable example in a sandbox like https://codesandbox.io?

Comment: Ok, I will try.

Comment: How can we import modules that we need to from sandbox ?